# How to pass down state and handlers in nested React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm having an issue passing down handlers through my React components.

I've tried following the instructions in the [Lifting State Up](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html) section of the React docs.

The idea is to have a Page with tabbed navigation, and each tab would render the display of some subpage.  I have a component `Page.js` for my overall page, and that's where I'm storing the activeTab state and where I think I should define the function that handles state change.  I then pass down the activeTab state and the handler as props to the `TabMenu.js` component, which in turn passes it down to the `TabItem.js` components.

The files:

Page.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import TabMenu from './TabMenu';
import FooPage from './FooPage';
import BarPage from './BarPage';

class Page extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            activeTab: 'foo'
        };

        this.setActiveTab = this.setActiveTab.bind(this);
    }

    getVisiblePage() {
        switch(this.state.activeTab) {
            case 'bar':
                return (
                    <FooPage />
                );
            case 'foo':
            default:
                return (
                    <BarPage />
                );
        }
    }

    setActiveTab(e, tab) {
        this.setState({
            activeTab: tab
        });
    }

    render() {
        var visiblePage = this.getVisiblePage();

        return (
            <section>
                <TabMenu
                    activeTab={ this.state.activeTab }
                    changeTabHandler={ this.setActiveTab }
                />
                { visiblePage }
            </section>
        );
    }
}

export default Page;
```

TabMenu.js:

```js
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';

import TabItem from './TabItem';

const TabMenu = ({ activeTab, changeTabHandler }) => {

    const tabs = [
        {
            key: 'foo',
            text: 'Foo Page',
        },
        {
            key: 'bar',
            text: 'Bar Page'
        },
    ];

    const tabItems = tabs.map((item) => (
        <TabItem
            key={ item.key } 
            item={ item }
            isActive={ item.key === activeTab }
            changeTabHandler={ changeTabHandler }
        />
    ));

    return (
        <nav id="TabMenu">
            <ul className="tab-items">
                { tabItems }
            </ul>
        </nav>
    );
};

TabMenu.displayName = 'TabMenu';

TabMenu.propTypes = {
    activeTab: PropTypes.string,
    changeTabHandler: PropTypes.func,
};

export default TabMenu;
```

TabItem.js

```js
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';

const TabItem = ({ item, changeTabHandler }) => {
    return (
        <li onClick={ changeTabHandler(item.key) }>
            { item.text }
        </li>
    );
};

TabItem.displayName = 'TabItem';

TabItem.propTypes = {
    item: PropTypes.object,
    changeTabHandler: PropTypes.func,
};

export default TabItem;
```

The end results is that my console overflows with 1000s of copies of the following error:

> warning.js:36 Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That infinite loop is because you have something inside the parent component's render function, which invoke `setState` or trigger some update to another component which affects the state of the origin or parent component which then will call render again.

in your case, it's because in TabItem.js,

```
<li onClick={ changeTabHandler(item.key) }>
            { item.text }
        </li>
```

actually invoke `changeTabHandler` immediately which will do setState in Page, and then TabItem will render and call `changeTabHandler` again

change it to

```
<li onClick={() => changeTabHandler(item.key) }>
            { item.text }
        </li>
```

Comment: Keep in mind that creating lot's of closures inside the render function can lead to slight performance drops depending if you have an older mobile.

Answer (score 1):

Your `changeTabHandler()` is getting invoked immediately, once for each `<li>` you are rendering. Change this:

```
<li onClick={ changeTabHandler(item.key) }>
```

to this:

```
<li onClick={ () => changeTabHandler(item.key) }>
```

Comment: Same answer as @kossel above, but thank you as well!